# TypeScript: fake type-safe field-based dependecy injection?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, prototype

I am working on wrapping AngularJS a little in TypeScript. One of the things I want to do is a sensible dependency injection syntax.

One possible solution is listing the dependencies as constructor arguments explicitly. The problem is without annotation, the parameter name has to match the service name, which is annoying. Also each sub-class must list all the arguments of the parent and their types, which is not very scalable.

So I am trying to do field based injection using this design:

```
class X {
    private scope = inject('$scope');
    private somethingElse = inject(); // Uses field name
}
```

Unfortunately, TypeScript does field initialization in the constructor function (instead of setting the prototype) so there's no way to figure out which fields need injection before creating an instance.

I am wondering is there any way around this?

Comment: You should be using static fields for this (Angular can only 'see' the static fields since those are the ones on the constructor function, which eliminates most of the problems you listed. Start with `static $inject = ['$scope']` and go from there.

Comment: Hi, this is one of the solutions I have considered and it have the same problem with constructor parameters. I.e. the sub-class must explicitly override the `$inject` from the parent class.
I am trying to use instance fields because they can be property type-checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can now be neatly done using decorators